# i am unable to get my snmp working on linux machine

Tags: php, linux, snmp

I tried each method on internet but can not figure out the problem . My script is giving error `"Call to undefined function snmp2_get()"` . same code is working on window machine by enabling php extension, how to enable & check if my snmp extnsion on linux is working. please help me .

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you without seeing what you already tried. In other words, post your code.
If your code is too big to post, create a small example that produces the error, and post that.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

In this case, you probably didn't import the snmp extension properly, but who knows without seeing the code?

Comment: my code is right . but my extension is not working in linux. how to enable that. in window it is running fine . but in linux it produces error . i tried with simple 1 line code $syscontact = snmp2_get("127.0.0.1", "public", "system.SysContact.0"); that is returning error . sudo service snmpd restart is successfull & restart neteork mang. services , but when i run ps -aux | grep snmp or run my file it give error , how to enable or reinstall my snmp extension for php in linux . it is very simple in window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to execute SNMP command from Linux terminal like as this

```
user@host $ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.3.3.242.4.2
```

but at the same time you are getting **Call to undefined function snmp2_get()**, it means PHP extenstion for SNMP communication is not installed . You can verify it by executing

```
user@host $ php -m
```

If output contains SNMP then module is already loaded and you should not get the error but if you are not finding any SNMP module in the output then you need to install it .

Install extenstion of SNMP only for your PHP version using **apt-get install** ( if you are on Debian based OS like Ubunutu) or use **yum install** (if you are on RPM based OS like as CentOS, Fedore, RHEL etc)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, e.g. `7.4` or `8.0`, try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php7.4-snmp
```

To see if it worked, watch the console for errors or do this:

```
php -m | grep snmp
```